# Replacing a string as long it's not followed by another in java?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have taken a whole file of code and placed it into a string: content. I need to replace all the words (class names) that start with A01 except those with A01Data and A01PrimaryFile with the name without the A01. (e.g. A01Numbers becomes Numbers I have tried:

```
content = content.replaceAll("A01(?!Data)|A01(?!PrimaryFile)", "");
```

but still the A01 gets taken away. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `|` in the negative lookahead:

```
content = content.replaceAll("A01(?!Data|PrimaryFile)", "");
```

Think about it - your nonworking code checks for either `A01` without `Data` in front, or `A01` without `PrimaryFile` in front. The `A01` can't have both in front at the same time, so it's always true.

In this code, it checks for `A01` with neither `Data` nor `PrimaryFile` in front.